# Unable to load VPN connection editor in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, gnome, network-manager, vpn

Some time ago I created a VPN connection using Ubuntus own Network Manager, which worked fine! Now, a few months later, I want to go in and edit the connections details, but instead I get this error: unable to load VPN connection editor.

[image]

Any idea how this could be solved?

[UPDATE]
Starting the connection manager manually with `nm-connection-editor` lets you edit the settings, but that still leaves the original error.

Comment: Do not go on `Network setting` in NM, go on `Network Connections`. Find connection in list, select, go right on `edit`

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Run

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

This will prompt for both your password, and a Y/n answer, please provide it with your password, and Y.

Comment: Yes, my issue was that I had only `network-manager-openvpn`, but not `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` installed.

Answer (score 19):

If you use a `vpnc` connection, like with FritzBox routers, run

```
sudo apt install network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

Answer (score 15):

The answers are quite specific. What helped me was indeed:

1. Running `nm-connection-editor` from the terminal
2. The following warning gives you the hint to the missing dependency

> Could not load editor VPN plugin for “org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.XYZ” (missing plugin file "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-vpn-plugin-XYZ-editor.so").

3. Install the missing dependency via `sudo apt-get install network-manager-XYZ-gnome`, i.e. using one of

- network-manager-l2tp-gnome
- network-manager-openconnect-gnome
- network-manager-pptp-gnome
- network-manager-vpnc-gnome
- network-manager-openvpn-gnome
- ...

With the missing /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-vpn-plugin-XYZ-editor.so now installed on your system, the network editor will continue working like a charm.

Comment: the other answers were helpful, but this was the actual key for me too... nothing else indicated i needed "network-manager-openconnect-gnome". Once installed, it brought up the interface I needed for cisco anyconnect. The problem was I did not realize that I didn't have the proper GUI, because the menu option was there and opened the wrong one. Just a note: I had to cross reference (through googling) the error message with https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/network-manager-openconnect-gnome/filelist to understand your comment... but now i see what was ACTUALLY missing. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu 20.04 it was network-manager-openconnect-gnome:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openconnect/+bug/1872074

Comment: and it works for Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-pptp-gnome
```

Comment: can you explain why this could help?

Comment: It is useful when we use a Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol and not OpenVPN. ;)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I knew what was going on with the pptp package, but thanks for explaining it as well anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar issue on Ubuntu 18.04 which persisted after installing all the dependencies listed in other answers.

Starting `nm-connection-editor` from terminal logged the warning below

> ** (nm-connection-editor:8495): WARNING **: 19:18:23.811: Could not load editor VPN plugin for “org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp”
>   (missing plugin file
>   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-vpn-plugin-l2tp-editor.so").

and the answer to that was

```
sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp-gnome
sudo service network-manager restart
```

as given in [How do I connect to L2TP over IPsec using Network Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934350/how-do-i-connect-to-l2tp-over-ipsec-using-network-manager).