# How do I connect to L2TP over IPsec using Network Manager?

Tags: networking, software-installation, network-manager, vpn

I am trying to connect to a L2TP over IPsec VPN I installed `network-manager-l2tp` and this repository : `ppa:nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp` and when I'm trying to add the connection from Network Connections I get this error:

```
Could not load editor VPN plugin for 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp' (missing plugin file "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-vpn-plugin-l2tp-editor.so").
```

How can I install the plugin?

Comment: What happens if you install `network-manager-l2tp-gnome`?

Comment: Well, it works :D

Comment: Alright, answer added for sake of completeness. Glad I could help!

Comment: For a command-line only approach see... https://askubuntu.com/a/983971/201083

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This appears to be because you just installed the command-line side of NetworkManager's L2TP support.

In order to use the GUI to configure L2TP VPNs as well, you will need to install the `network-manager-l2tp-gnome` package like so:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp-gnome
```

Following this, a restart of `nm-applet` may be necessary to make NetworkManager see the change. In order to do this, just run the following:

```
killall nm-applet
nm-applet &
disown
```