# Ubuntu 18.04 VPN Connection

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a problem with the GUI network-manager for VPN. When I use it I get an error message:

> unable to load VPN network connection editor

If I use the terminal it works. How can I get the network GUI to work?. Any ideas?.

Comment: Just a note that if anyone is trying to install/add PPTP to the Network Manager the command sudo apt-get install network-manager-pptp-gnome

Answer (score 20):

I have just had the same problem which I fixed. I was attempting to add an OpenVPN connection (you haven't stated which type of VPN you're using) but the idea will work.
I already had openvpn and network-manager-openvpn installed via apt, but I needed to add network-manager-openvpn-gnome

`sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn-gnome`

then restarted network manager (this kills networking until it's fully restarted)

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

After this, I could open system settings again, go to networking and add my OpenVPN stuff.

This has been an issue for a couple of years and was answered here:
[Unable to load VPN connection editor in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579159/unable-to-load-vpn-connection-editor-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Cheers

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to install OpenVPN.  I have both network-manager-openvpn and network-manager-openvpn-gnome installed.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to install OpenVPN.  I have both network-manager-openvpn and network-manager-openvpn-gnome installed.   For some reason can I not get the GUI to work. I just goes on/off with no error message. In terminal it works find with sudo openvpn 'etc....'                    It worked good in Ubuntu 17.10 and previous version...                                      Any thoughts?

Comment: If you click the GUI icon for network, the pull-down shows the usual network connection, the VPN option (if you managed to add a VPN successfully earlier), battery status (if a laptop), your username, and the three buttons at the bottom - settings, lockscreen, and shutdown. I click on VPN and it shows me the OpenVPN connections I had set up earlier plus a button for VPN settings. If you didn't successfully set up a VPN then this option is not in the drop-down. In that case, click on the Settings button, choose Network when the box appears and the + sign next to VPN to add. Maybe you did this?

Comment: Yes all done. It's when I try to start the OpenVPN t just won't start. It work fine in a Terminal window....

Comment: I am following this thread https://www.aspkin.com/forums/ip-address/109664-solved-softether-client-linux-tutoral.html and still I can't have the VPN running on Ubuntu 18

Comment: Same problem as @AndersWeinberg

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my Ubuntu running in VMWare fusion. This works for me:
Open network settings window, click on "Ifupdown (ens33)". Then you can connect VPN.

On every reboot you would need to redo it.

Answer (score 0):

- Made sure I had the following packages installed:

`sudo apt-get install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome`

- Restart Network Manager:

`sudo service network-manager restart`

- Made sure OpenVPN was running:

`sudo service openvpn restart`

I noticed the following errors in syslog `grep VPN /var/log/syslog`, can also check them look for them with `systemctl status network-manager`:

`Failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were available for this request.`

- Opened connection with `nmcli`, solved the issue.

`nmcli --ask connection up VPN-CONNECTION-NAME`